# Get Last table from SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure SP1 which is returning two tables T1 and T2 using SELECT Statements. I want to perform some operation on T2 in another Stored Procedure SP2. Can someone guide me how I can do that?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that with SP, what you need is a table valued function.

Comment: There is no way of accessing just the second result set from a stored procedure in TSQL.

If both result sets are union compatible then you can `INSERT INTO @T EXEC YourProc` but this will insert **both** result sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Change SP1 to save T2 to a table, in addition to returning it using a SELECT. Then use that table as input for SP2.

**Option 2**

If you can't change SP1, you can catch the output of the stored procedure in a table. Check out this question on StackOverflow on how to do that by using OPENROWSET or by defining a temp table in advance: [How to SELECT * INTO [temp table] FROM [stored procedure]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure).

This option *will not work* if T1 and T2 do not have the same definition. If they have the same definition, you can import both result sets into **one** table as follows:

```
--create a temporary table with the same definition as T1 and T2
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    Col1 SOME DATATYPE,
    Col2 SOME DATATYPE
);

--fill your temp table with the result sets of T1 and T2
INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC [dbo].[SP1];
```

But then you have to deal with the T1-plus-T2 table instead of T2.

So it seems option 1 is your best bet.

Comment: Actually I was trying to achieve it using something like option 2. But thanks for telling the option 1. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! I can imagine you wanted to go the option 2 route, must say I was slightly surprised that there seems to be no obvious way to handle multiple result sets from a SP in SQL Server.